# Why 1 in For loop?

Tags: for-loop

```
for(let i = 1; i<=5; i++)
{
  console.log(i);
}
```

Here I don't know why 1 is printed since the condition of i <=5 and it should add 1 right? So it should print 2 first instead of 1.Thankyou.

Comment: console.log will display the current value of i - which goes from 1 to 5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first value is 1.
i++ will be executed after the loop is done.

```
for(let i = 1; i<=5; i++)
{
  console.log(i);
}<--- i++;
```

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop in your question is like doing this in a `while` loop:

```
let i = 1;
while (i <= 5) {
    console.log(i);
    i++;
}
```

So, it's printing the current value of i and after it finishes all the statements inside the braces, finally adds 1 (`i++`) to the current value of `i`.